# rails: find model objects where foreign key date within certain range

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model GoalAssessments with a foreign key encounter_id.  The Encounter model has an encounter_date.  I want to find all instances of GoalAssessment that have an encounter_date within a certain range of dates.  I've tried the following join:

```
GoalAssessments.joins(encounter: {encounter_date: @start_date..@end_date})
```

This generates an active record relation without error, but then when I try to iterate over the active record relation, I get an `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `joins` incorrectly. The condition is expressed in the where clause. Otherwise, if you want to add the condition to the join part, you need to fully express the join part with a string or with arel. Try

```
GoalAssessment.joins(:encounter).
    where(encounters: {encounter_date: @start_date..@end_date})
```

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't sure how to access associated encounter fields from a GoalAssessment object by just using active record assocations.  I wasn't able to use GoalAssessment.where(encounter_date: @start_date..@end_date)

Comment: Yes.  Thanks very much!